# Regular expression to delete only two occurrences of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string

```
"{\"title\": \"Option 1\", \"description\": \"This is the \"FIRST OPTION\" in the list.\"}"
```

I need to replace the escaped quotes around FIRST OPTION with ampersand quot; so that it looks like this:

```
"{\"title\": \"Option 1\", \"description\": \"This is the &quot;FIRST OPTION&quot; in the list.\"}"
```

The only way I can think of is to change the two \" occurrences after **\"description\": \"** (it has to be only two because near the end of the string there are escaped quotes that need to stay like this) but I can't figure out the syntax (I'm very new to regular expressions).

Is there a way of achieving this with regular expressions in JS?

**Update:** Forgot to mention that FIRST OPTION is just an example, it can be any string, I need to remove the escaped quotes around it.

Comment: This site will help you build your regex: https://regex101.com/

Comment: can you not `JSON.parse()` your string, then do the operation on just the description, then `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: This is clearly a JSON string, but... is this something you _received_ or something you are going to _send?_  What do you intend to do with the result? This seems to me to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) where you have some issue and you've already decided the way to handle it is to change the `\"` into `&quot;` - but - depending on what you are _really_ trying to do, that may not be the best approach in the first place.  What is the actual issue with those quotes? Describe the _real_ underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

Find `/\\"(?=FIRST OPTION)|(FIRST OPTION)\\"/`
Replace `$1&quot;`

https://regex101.com/r/Nwnr13/2

---

Or, if first option is required to have both escaped quotes, then this

Find `/\\"(FIRST OPTION)\\"/`
Replace `&quot;$1&quot;`

https://regex101.com/r/tp9I5T/2

Answer (score 0):

See this Example:

```js
var text="{\"title\": \"Option 1\", \"description\": \"This is the \"FIRST OPTION\" in the list.\"}";
text=text.replace(/([\{|:|,])(?:[\s]*)(")/g, "$1'")
.replace(/(?:[\s]*)(?:")([\}|,|:])/g, "'$1")
.replace(/["]/gi, '&quot;').replace(/[']/gi, '"');

text=JSON.stringify(text);
console.log(text);
  
text=JSON.parse(text);
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score -1):

Starting with your JSON string the simplest thing to understand and the safest thing is to turn that back in to a Javascript object, operate on just the `description` field, and turn it back into a String.
JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify() will do that.
      (as suggested by @jdubjdub but not written up, so here I go)

You give this as your string:

```
"{\"title\": \"Option 1\", \"description\": \"This is the \"FIRST OPTION\" in the list.\"}"
```

To assign that to a variable for our testing purposes, additional escaping is required:

```
var yourstring = "{\"title\": \"Option 1\", \"description\": \"This is the \\\"FIRST OPTION\\\" in the list.\"}";
```

You will then `var obj = JSON.parse(yourstring)` to make an object, you'll operate on just `obj.description` to replace the quotes, then you'll `var changedstring = JSON.stringify(obj)` to end up with a string again.

```js
var yourstring = "{\"title\": \"Option 1\", \"description\": \"This is the \\\"FIRST OPTION\\\" in the list.\"}";
console.log('Original String:');
console.log(yourstring);

var obj = JSON.parse(yourstring);
console.log('String parsed into an Object:');
console.log(obj);

var newdesc = obj.description.replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
obj.description = newdesc;
console.log('Modified Object:');
console.log(obj);

var newstring = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log('New String:');
console.log(newstring);
```